# EMR Cluster creation using Java

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-emr

I am trying to create an EMR Cluster using Java. I have created the jar file and put that into a lambda function. I'm calling the lambda from AWS Step functions. I created the maven package including the AWS JAVA SDK dependencies and also imported all the packages

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import com.amazonaws.auth.*;
 import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
 import com.amazonaws.auth.PropertiesCredentials;
 import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.*;
 import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.AddJobFlowStepsRequest;
 import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.AddJobFlowStepsResult;
 import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.RunJobFlowRequest;
 import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.*;
 import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.HadoopJarStepConfig;
 import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.StepConfig;
 import com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.util.StepFactory;
 import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
 import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
 import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
```

public class CreateCluster {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("access key", "secret key");
    // myApp={[Hadoop]};
    AmazonElasticMapReduceClient emr = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(credentials);
    String COMMAND_RUNNER = "command-runner.jar";
    String DEBUGGING_COMMAND = "state-pusher-script";
    String DEBUGGING_NAME = "Setup Hadoop Debugging";

    StepFactory stepFactory = new StepFactory();

    StepConfig enabledebugging = new StepConfig()
            .withName(DEBUGGING_NAME)
            .withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.TERMINATE_CLUSTER)
            .withHadoopJarStep(new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                    .withJar(COMMAND_RUNNER)
                    .withArgs(DEBUGGING_COMMAND));

    RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
            .withName("REMR")
            .withReleaseLabel("emr-5.16.0")
            .withSteps(enabledebugging)
            //  .withApplications(myApp)
            .withLogUri("s3n://r.base.ihm/emr-log/")
            .withServiceRole("service_role")
            .withJobFlowRole("jobflow_role")
            .withInstances(new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
                    .withEc2KeyName("emr")
                    .withEc2SubnetId("subnet-d1fbb8ee")
                    .withInstanceCount(3)
                    .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(false)
                    .withMasterInstanceType("m4.large")
                    .withSlaveInstanceType("m4.large"));

    RunJobFlowResult result = emr.runJobFlow(request);

}
```

}
but still I'm getting the error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
>
> {
>       "errorMessage": "Error loading class com.ihm.base.spark.CreateCluster: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials",
>       "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"
>      }

Any ideas on what I am missing here?

Comment: Your missing the posting of your code. If you are using example code post the link also.

Comment: @JohnHanley : I'm using the sample code provided by AWS in the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/calling-emr-with-java-sdk.html

Comment: Where are you getting the code that is referencing CreateCluster? Edit your question and include all the code, don't make us guess.

Comment: @JohnHanley included the code. Apologies.

Comment: From first look, your problem is that you are specifying your Lambda entry point wrong or you have forgotten to include your code in the package that your are uploading. CreateCluster is your own class. Is your package name `com.ihm.base.spark.CreateCluster`?

Comment: @JohnHanley: I have the package name at the begining package com.ihm.base.spark;